# Datadog parse array of json

Tags: datadog

I have array of json`s as log in Datadog.
Example:

```
[{name:"jon"} , {name:"mike"}]
```

How can I parse inner json`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if parsing is the right word here.

Logs Management from DD is there to help analysing logs to help build insights about the app.

so, the question here. what kind of insight are you looking for?

let me come up with one.
Given that the log payload is:

```
{
   users: [{ name: "Jon" }, { name: "Mike" }]
}
```

you want to list all the `name`s included in each log, so, later on, you can look up for all the logs that have a `user` with the name of `"Mike"`

then, you can add a `String Builder Processor` to your pipeline. where it will lookup for every item in the array and map it to another attribute.

[image]

this will generate a new attribute of `payload.result` holds the names separated by `,`

```
result: Jon, Mike
```

then, you can create a `facet` for this attribute and lookup for it
ex. given the facet's name is `@payload.result`

```
@payload.result:*Mike*
// or
@payload.result:*Jon*
```

PS. processors help you reshape the payload of a log to pretty much any format. of course, it can get complicated.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui